# How to do popcount or count bits on arbitrarily long bit sequence in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

This looks like it works well on integers that are within the max integer size in JavaScript:

```
function bitCount (n) {
  var bits = 0
  while (n !== 0) {
    bits += bitCount32(n | 0)
    n /= 0x100000000
  }
  return bits
}

function bitCount32 (n) {
  n = n - ((n >> 1) & 0x55555555)
  n = (n & 0x33333333) + ((n >> 2) & 0x33333333)
  return ((n + (n >> 4) & 0xF0F0F0F) * 0x1010101) >> 24
}
```

I'm wondering though how to count bits generally, on any sized bit stream, efficiently, ideally without converting to string.

Comment: There are no bit streams in JavaScript. The closest is probably `ArrayBuffer`, is that what you mean? Get a 32-bit view on it and run your function.

Comment: Yes, basically just a long ArrayBuffer of arbitrary size.

Comment: I would just loop over it as bytes (perhaps shorts), and sum bitcounts from a pre-computed array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment with the lookup table, roughly:

```js
var lookup=new Uint8Array(256);
for(var i=0;i<256;i++){
  var c=0;
  for(var j=i;j;j>>=1)
    if(j&1)c++;
  lookup[i]=c;
}
function count(arr){
  var arr8=new Uint8Array(arr);
  return arr8.reduce((a,e)=>a+lookup[e],0);
}

console.log(count(new Uint8Array([0x12,0x34,0x56,0x78,0x9A,0xBC,0xDE,0xF])));
                                  //11   21   22   31   22   32   33   4 = 32
```

Of course the table-generation could use your magic too.

Answer (score 1):

If you know your buffer will have length divisible by 4,

```
let array32 = new Uint32Array(buffer);
let numBits = array32.reduce((a, e) => a + bitCount32(e), 0);
```

Otherwise probably tevemadar's suggestion is better, use `Uint8Array` and count bits in a byte, not in a dword.

Comment: Ehehe, I believed you in the middle of the night. But `reduce`: *`initialValue` [...] If no initial value is supplied, the first element in the array will be used.*

Comment: Eh happens when you don’t test... How about now?

Comment: I guess it should work, at least mine does, and this was the only problem with it.